# Getting 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll in the exit terminal when disconnecting the sshclient with Renci.SshNet

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

The method I use is as follow :

```
public int ExecuteShellCommand(string a_command, bool log = false)
    {
        int res = 0;
        try
        {
            using (var sshclient = new SshClient(m_connNfo))
            {
                sshclient.Connect();

                using (var cmd = sshclient.CreateCommand(a_command + " >&2"))
                {
                    var resultExe = cmd.Execute();
                    if (log)
                    {
                        Console.Write(resultExe);
                        var extended = cmd.ExtendedOutputStream;
                        var reader = new StreamReader(extended);
                        Console.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                    res = cmd.ExitStatus;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return -1;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

The m_connNfo is created with the line :

```
m_connNfo = new ConnectionInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[IP], 22, User,
       new AuthenticationMethod[]{
            // Pasword based Authentication
            new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(User,ApiInstance.GetPass())
             });
```

This works perfectly and do want I expect it to do, the problem is when the '}' of the "try" is reach, so when the using is closed, I get an "System.ObjectDisposedException in System.dll" in the exit terminal.
It also happens when I do :
`sshclient.Disconnect();`
before closing the using.

I wish to understand why it does that.

Does someone understand why I get this exception ?

Comment: What does the inner exception say? Does it clarify anything? Right now it is hard for us to determine what object causes the exception to be thrown

Comment: That exactly the point of my question, there is no inner exception, only a 
'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll' that rise in the terminal once the sshclient is disposed of

Comment: That would mean it should end in the catch clause. Have you tried adding a name to the exception parameter like so: `catch (Exception e)` if you hover over it (e) during debugging this should allow you to investigate a bit deeper.

Comment: As said in the question, the code does what I need it to do, it will not go in the catch

Comment: In your question you state that when the final } is reached it throws this error. This is still within the try clause. Could it be possible that you dispose the class which executes this function?

Comment: That SshClient is yours or if not you have the source code?

Comment: There is no error thrown within the try { } or anywhere else, the class is not disposed.

Comment: I'm using Renci.SshNet for the SshClient, totally forgot about that... I'll check into that

Comment: A guess. You use a StreamReader that itself is disposable and if not prevented will try to dispose the stream it looks at when it gets disposed. So in current code you have two objects that will(or may) try to dispose the ExtendedOutputStream. So you should dispose the StreamReader and use the "leaveOpen" parameter when creating the StreamReader so only the command will dispose the stream.  It definetly cleaner code and maybe fix this on the way.

Comment: @Ralf that does seem plausible, however I would expect there to be a more detailed exception. It feels like the exception happens in an external service. Maybe the SshClient is trying to dispose of the command whilst it was already disposed of? In which case you would be spot on. However I don't see how the streamreader would dispose of itself without any using statement or direct dispose calls

Comment: @Roe Thats why i added the maybe ;) ObjectDisposedExceptions aren't typically thrown when you dispose something but when you try to use something that already has been disposed. So the still floating around reader might do something with the disposed stream other then disposing just because it still lives.

Comment: I commented everything in the if(log) condition, to test your guess about the streamreader. Unfortunatly, the exception still rize in the terminal. My guess is the error comes from the Dispose from the SshCommand cmd, I'm currently looking into that

Comment: @Alex have you tried commenting every thing inside the execute statement. If the exception still arises the problem is located somewhere else. If it doesn't throw an exception, slowly start adding back lines until it throws the exception. At this point i'm fairly certain this exception is caused by something outside of this function. Maybe code running on a separate thread (if you make use of asynchronous code).

Comment: I removed both the "using", and the exception is no more. Looks like the using was trying to dispose of something that was already disposed inside the SshCommand. Thank both for the guidance

Comment: Glad you were able to find the issue! I briefly looked through the source code. Seems like CreateCommand is only responsible for returning a command without further functionality. This library isn't very keen on explaining exactly how to use it. Goodluck on the project! Don't forget to post your finding as an answer @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Roe and Ralf, I discovered that the error was coming from the dispose of the SshClient.
It's an error that comes from an old version of Renci.SshNet 2017, this bug is **fixed** in the 2020 version.

So to fix this problem, I had to update my RencySsh dll to the newest version.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as accepted answer. That way people can see that the question has an accepted answer.